# Managing(adding/deleting,etc) users in a squashfs(RO file system) with a small R/W partition

Tags: login, embedded, shadow, squashfs, passwd

I'm using squashfs as the file system on a board which is RO, along with a small jffs2 partition which is R/W. The files corresponding to user management, i.e `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` & `/etc/shadow` are all located on the `RO` partition. Now, there's no way a user may add, delete or modify his credentials using commands such as `useradd`, `usermod`,etc.
I'm looking for a way to provide user management options in this system (maybe by using the jffs2 partion?). I'm aware of 2 possible solutions:

1. Move the `etc/{passwd,group,shadow}` files to the R/W partition & symlink them to the RO partion.
2. Bind mount these files with their respective copies in on the R/W partion.

The problem with solution 1 is that commands like useradd don't accept symlinks & even if they do(by modifying their source) I'm not sure how either solution will be able to edit the `/home/{username}` directory while adding/deleting/modifying the home directory name as it's RO.

Squashfs is commonly used for small & embedded systems, so what exactly is the solution that is preferred for such scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

You can move your files you need to be writable in a directory on the jjfs2 partition and use unionfs to join the directory to your squashfs image mounted on a loop. there is a nice tutorial here: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html

Comment: That seems to be a nice solution but I have some doubts. I can move /etc/{passwd,group...} files to the jffs2 but that means I'll also have to move the /home directory to jffs2 as well, as the directories within it contain the usernames. So, for a user to modify his home directory, the entire /home directory must be writeable I guess? That defeats the purpose of using squashfs itself! I need all the contents below /home/{}/ to be RO. Only the names within {} need to editable.